# rstudio build and reload won't load package

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-package

I've been playing around trying to build a toy r package. It used to work fine, but from some point when I run build and reload, somethings goes wrong and I cannot execute the code:

```
> hello()
Error: could not find function "hello"
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: export the function using #' @export right above the hello <-

Comment: Thanks you @mr.joshuagordon. I tried doing so but it still doesn't work. In addition, I thought creating package "out of the box" using rstudio should work without further annotations.

Comment: You need to run "Document" (CTRL-Shift-D or CMD-Shift-D or select the option under the "More…" menu under the Build tab) after adding that Roxygen comment and before building the package. See [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) for more info. RStudio has no way to know what you want to do with anything unless you tell it.

Comment: Thanks you @hrbrmstr. Indeed when I explicitly create the documentation using devtools::document(), everything works fine. Interestingly it does _not_ work if I run it via Ctrl+Shift+D via Ctrl+Shift+B (with the settings as in the link you referred to).